# Django annotate with model values

Tags: sql, django, annotations

The Django [docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) give the following example for annotations:

```py
for store in Store.objects.all():
    store.min_price # Error! min_price not defined!
for store in Store.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('books__price')):
    store.min_price # Fine
```

However, we only annotated a single field. We only know what the *price* of the cheapest book is, but not exactly which is the cheapest *book*. What if I wanted the result of the annotation be precisely that book, not just its price? (I'll call this function or class `AggregateRelation`)

```py
for store in Store.objects.annotate(
   cheapest_book=AggregateRelation('books__price', Min)
):
    store.cheapest_book.price
    store.cheapest_book.title
```

Is there a way to do this?

I checked up [`FilteredRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) but that's only useful for filtering. It does not truly retrieve the instances.

Comment: well, if there's a way in SQL, you could run a raw SQL query. I know that's probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) you are using PostgreSQL, then I think there's an answer using [`.distinct(fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
Book.objects.order_by('store_id', 'price').distinct('store_id')
```

should get you the cheapest book for each store if I've understood the documentation (linked above) right. Adding `select_related()` should mean that you don't hit the DB again when you refer to `book.store.whatever`

If you don't have PostgreSQL I think you can use a [`SubQuery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). The following is my attempt to follow the documentation:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

cheapest = Book.objects.filter(store=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('price')
stores = Store.objects.annotate(cheapest_book_pk=Subquery(cheapest.values('pk')[:1]))
```

Something like this will get you a list of Store objects, each annotated with the pk of the cheapest book that it is selling.

Please tell me whether I've got this right!